# Closing lid on Crunchbang

Tags: power-management, laptop, crunchbang, sleep

I'm running Crunchbang on a laptop. I can't seem to find an option to toggle if the laptop goes to sleep when the lid closes. There are certain times where I want to put the laptop away or close it but still have it do some crunching on some long running task.

Is there a place to toggle this option?

Comment: Do you mean 'CrunchBang'?  http://crunchbang.org/

Comment: yes crunchbang.

Answer (score 2):

For me it's at Settings -> Power Management. The command line would be

> xfce4-power-manager --customize